# trouble compiling a lkm in ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm doing some exercises to introduce operating system concepts and I am asked to create a loadable kernel module in linux in c. I copied the code from the book along with a makefile and am trying to compile it and I'm getting many errors

source hello.c

```
/*
* File: hello.c
* Purpose: To demonstrate a simple kernel module.
*/

#include <linux/module.h> /* for all kernel modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h> /* for KERN_INFO */

int init_module(void) /* module entry point */
{
   printk(KERN_INFO "Hello , user!\n");
   return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void) /* module exit point */
{
   printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye , user!\n");
   return;
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("My first cool kernel module");
MODULE_AUTHOR("user");
```

Makefile

```
obj-m += hello.o

KDIR := /usr/src/linux-headers-$(shell uname -r)

default:
   $(MAKE) -Wall -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
```

error:

```
user@user-VirtualBox:/media/sf_shared_folder$ make hello
cc     hello.c   -o hello
hello.c: In function ‘init_module’:
hello.c:11:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printk’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   11 |    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello , user!\n");
      |    ^~~~~~
hello.c:11:11: error: ‘KERN_INFO’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   11 |    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello , user!\n");
      |           ^~~~~~~~~
hello.c:11:11: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
hello.c:11:20: error: expected ‘)’ before string constant
   11 |    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello , user!\n");
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                    )
hello.c: In function ‘cleanup_module’:
hello.c:17:11: error: ‘KERN_INFO’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   17 |    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye , user!\n");
      |           ^~~~~~~~~
hello.c:17:20: error: expected ‘)’ before string constant
   17 |    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye , user!\n");
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                    )
hello.c: At top level:
hello.c:21:16: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant
   21 | MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
      |                ^~~~~
hello.c:22:20: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant
   22 | MODULE_DESCRIPTION("My first cool kernel module");
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
hello.c:23:15: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant
   23 | MODULE_AUTHOR("user");
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [<builtin>: hello] Error 1
```

Comment: The makefile you write implies that you would build your module by running `make`. Why do you run the compiler **directly** (`cc hello.c -o hello`)? Note, that for build the kernel module the makefile should be named as `Makefile`. Naming as `makefile` won't work.

Comment: No, `make hello` is wrong too. You need to build the module using plain `make`. (Look: your makefile doesn't have a target `hello`. But it has a default target. Exactly this target is built when you run `make` without parameters.

Comment: thanks mate, I never would have thought of that myself. I appreciate it